# How to specify the size of points in matplotlib point size legend

Tags: python, matplotlib

My goal is to (as elegantly as possible) make a legend for a scatter plot that shows the minimum, medium, and maximum of the scatter point sizes.

I am experimenting with using the `legend_elements` function. I've looked through the [demo](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_with_legend.html) and documentation, but it doesn't look like there is a way to do what I want with this function.

Next, I tried summoning the same number of points that I have. The reasoning being that I can select the first, middle, and last points to approximate the minimum, mean, and maximum. However, the minimum and maximum points that the legend shows are not the minimum and maximum points in the data. Why did summoning the same number of point legends as sampled points not yield the minimum and maximum? Is it possible to use a helper function like `legend_elements` to construct a legend that shows the minimum, medium, and maximum point sizes in a scatter plot?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# ensure repeatability
np.random.seed(123456)

NSAMPS = 100 # Number of scattered points

idx = [0, NSAMPS // 2, -1] # min-medium-max coordinates

# randomly sample x, y, and size from 0 to 100
RandomMatrix = 100 * np.random.random((NSAMPS, 3))

# make scatter plot
sc = plt.scatter(RandomMatrix[:, 0], RandomMatrix[:, 1], s=RandomMatrix[:, 2])

# recover the same number of element sizes
sizes = sc.legend_elements("sizes", num=NSAMPS)

# parse the sizes for the first, middle, and last entries
args = (list(np.array(sizes[0])[idx]), list(np.array(sizes[1])[idx])) 

# show that the estimated min and max sizes are 1.6 and 98.4, respectively
plt.legend(*args, **{'title': "I want the true min-med-max here! [thanks for taking a look:)]", 'bbox_to_anchor': (1, 1)})

# save figure
plt.savefig('mybigprobelem')

# show that the true minimum and maximum sizes are 1.06 and 98.9
# (I wish for these numbers/sizes to be in the first and third legend positions)
print('True min-max: ', RandomMatrix[:, 2].min(), RandomMatrix[:, 2].max())
```

[image]

```
True min-max:  1.0692999366311629 98.89493616046823
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace `args` with:

```
args = (list(np.array(sizes[0])[idx]), np.sort(RandomMatrix[:,2])[idx])
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Does the size of each point exactly correspond to the number beside it in the legend? It looks like this just changes the legend text but not the corresponding point sizes...